# Nginx location match with any number at the end

Tags: angular, nginx

I would want my nginx location to match like below

> localhost/#/my-test/2020_05_000234.

Have tried but it says not found.
Below is my location I tried

```
location /my-test/ {
proxy_pass http://localhost:90/
}
```

Comment: Do you have an actual `#` in the URL or is it a placeholder? The `#` stands for fragment identifier. It has nothing to do with a server (it won't be able to see it), so there is no possibility to match up a location by it on the server. The matching happens against specific ID in your HTML, by the browsers.

Comment: I do have # in the URL. I am actually redirecting my angular application with localhost/#/my-test/2020_05_000234.. I actually want to match with /my-test/2020_05_000234 and proxy_pass to another

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
location ~* ^/my-test/(.+)$ {
}
```

Comment: location ~*/my-test/(.+)$ { } says 404 not found